# can we load one row at a time into snowflake table using python?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a .csv file to be loaded into **snowsql table** using **python API**.
My question is how to **load one row at a time**, so to check if every row is successfully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible, I do not recommend you to do single inserts to Snowflake:

```
import snowflake.connector
import csv

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
...
) 

cursor = ctx.cursor()


with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3 )
                          VALUES(%s, %s, %s )
                       """, row)

cursor.close()
```

You can validate the files before COPY command:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#validating-staged-files

And you can also check the errors after COPY command:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html